# React Warning: setState(...) Can only update a mounted or mounting component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, flux

I have a problem: I'm building my first app with React/ReactNative + Flux and I obtain this warning:

> setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This
>   usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op. Please check the code for the undefined component.

Above my code:

```
class ListMovies extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2}),
            loaded: false
        };
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        ApiListMovies.getMovies();
        ListMoviesStore.addChangeListener(() => this._onChange());
    };

    componentWillUnmount() {
        ListMoviesStore.removeChangeListener(() => this._onChange());
    };

    _onChange() {
        console.log(this.state);
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(ListMoviesStore.getListMovies()),
            loaded: true
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <ListView
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderMovie}
                style={styles.listView}
            />
        );
    }

    renderMovie(movie) {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Image
                    source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
                    style={styles.thumbnail}
                />
                <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.year}>{movie.year}</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = ListMovies;
```

As you can see I'm showing you a list of movies in very simple way. Now show a snippet that change the view. My problem comes when I change the page in my app that change from page showing films to a showing info.

```
class TabsView extends React.Component {

    //do stuff...

  renderContent() {
    switch (this.state.tab) {
      case 'List Movies':
        return <ListMoviesView/>;

      case 'Info':
        return <InfoView/>;

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.content} key={this.state.tab}>
            {this.renderContent()}
        </View>
    );
  }
}

module.exports = TabsView;
```

I put one log() in function _onChange() of first snippet (because the problem lives there) and when when I change page the function is called several times and obtain the above warning. How can fix it? Where am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: seems you didnt remove the listener. so the _onChange function will trigger even you changed page. i'm not familiar with flux but, can a listener has no sign that to be listen?

Answer (score 0):

You are providing a *new* function instance to each of your **add** and **remove** event listener functions. Therefore the remove will not work as intended as it is targeting a different function instance, and the change events still get the events fired.

I am guessing that you were passing in anonymous functions to the add/remove event listeners to maintain your scope for the `this.setState` calls.  You can maintain scope by using an anonymous function bound to a class property, and then simply reference the property in your add/remove calls, like so:

```
    componentDidMount() {
        ApiListMovies.getMovies();
        ListMoviesStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
    };

    componentWillUnmount() {
        ListMoviesStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
    };

    // We use anonymous function bound to the class property, this
    // will maintain our scope.
    _onChange = () => {
        console.log(this.state);
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(ListMoviesStore.getListMovies()),
            loaded: true
        });
    };
```

Note: the above relies on [class properties syntax](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) which is in proposal and is enabled via babel stage 1 at the moment.  If you don't have this you can create the function within the constructor call.  Like so:

```
 class ListMovies extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     this.state = {
      dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2}),
      loaded: false
    };

    // We use anonymous function bound to the class property, this
    // will maintain our scope.
    this._onChange = () => {
        console.log(this.state);
        this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(ListMoviesStore.getListMovies()),
            loaded: true
        });
    };
   }

   componentDidMount() {
     ApiListMovies.getMovies();
     ListMoviesStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
   };

   componentWillUnmount() {
     ListMoviesStore.removeChangeListener(this._onChange);
   };
```